# What to look in a camera for underwater surveillance?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera, underwater

I am working on an ROV and I'm supposed to choose a lowlight camera for it. The goal is underwater surveillance of species and objects. The waterbody is sometimes a pool, large water pipes, lakes, and sometimes the sea too.

What specs (such as FOV, resolution, bitrate, fps) should I compare in cameras to select the best one?

Also, there are photography cameras such as GoPro, Canon etc and then the robotics camera for e.g., the [BlueRobotics camera](https://bluerobotics.com/store/sensors-sonars-cameras/cameras/cam-usb-low-light-r1/), [DWE camera](https://dwe.ai/products/explorehd#technical-data) etc. What's the difference between the photography cameras and robotics camera? From which type should i choose a camera from?

Comment: Is your goal still photography, or video? If video, this question might be better suited to [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com)